# Sharefolder is not created on guest machine

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I followed this tutorial to create a virtual machine with ubuntu: 
https://linus.nci.nih.gov/bdge/installUbuntu.html
The last section in the tutorial is about how to use shared folders. I did everything that is described there and `sudo adduser username vboxsf` worked just fine and my user has been added to the sharefolder. But now on my guest machine I can't find the shared folder. In the tutorial they say, it would now be created in computer->filesystem->media->sf_sharefoldername but a systemwide search for "sf_" didn't give any results. Also the path computer->filesystem doesn't exist. Instead I can access computer->media. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong/where the folder is and what it's name will be?

I don't think it's a duplicate of the question you linked, @N0rbert. As described in the tutorial that I linked, I did use the automount option of virtualbox

Shared folder settings:
[image]

Comment: @N0rbert Not a duplicate, I already found that question before. Doesn't solve my problem. I don't have problems accessing the folder, there just is no folder. Also: see my edit to the question.

Comment: I think it exists. Did you tried to run `sudo mount -t vboxsf windows_share /media/windows_share` (where `windows_share` is folder name)? What is your host system? Please add screenshot of shared folders tab (similar to [one from the article](https://linus.nci.nih.gov/bdge/images/ubuntu/image055.png)) to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert that command resulted in "mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory". I'll edit screenshots, wait a moment

Comment: So you should change the command above to something like `sudo mount -t vboxsf share /mnt` (the `/mnt` is mount-point, it should exist).

Comment: @N0rbert ok, well this works, thanks. But why is this /media/share not created? And now I can only create files on mnt using `sudo`, how can I change the permission there so I can also drag&drop files into the sharefolder?

Comment: @N0rbert Nevermind, I figured it out now, thanks for your help. But anyway: I don't think it was a duplicate. Maybe you can add an answer saying that you can create the folder yourself using `sudo mkdir /media/share` and then mounting it. It might seem obvious for someone who's at home in linux, but for us beginners it's helpful, trust me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood what was changed. On modern Ubuntu versions automatically created mount-points are in *unsername* subfolder of `/media` - that is `/media/username` (instead of simple `/media`).

So if you have installed VirtualBox guest-additions, setup auto-mount

[image: AutoMount share]

and reboot the guest, then it should be shown as `sf_mountpoint` on the desktop (GNOME - left, MATE - right):

[image: GNOME desktop] or [image: MATE desktop]

and in the filemanager

[image: mountpoint in Nautilus] or [image: mountpint in Caja]

---

The link to official documentation - is [4 Guest Additions → 4.3 Shared folders → 4.3.2 Automatic mounting](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf#subsection.4.3.2).

Comment: Well, the folder was just not created. Also not in /media/username, I checked that before asking the question. I had to manually create and mount it now, I guess the automount option just didn't work at all. The only thing that was in the /media/username folder, was the .iso image of guest-additions. Except for that this is a good answer.

Comment: Looks strange. I have tested this method on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS amd64 host with VirtualBox 5.1.38 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS guests (GNOME and MATE). Both have created mountpoints after enabling automount and rebooting the guest.

Comment: Don't know why It was not created, but I tried rebooting and it still didn't happen. My host system is Kubuntu 16.04.5 LTS with Dolphin (as far as I understood Dolphin, Gnome and Mate are all filemanagers?!)

Comment: K in Kubuntu means KDE. KDE is a desktop environment (DE) with Dolphin file-manager. GNOME and MATE are other/alternative DEs with respectively Nautilus and Caja as file-managers :) The host DE should not cause guest problems.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. All these names are very confusing when you first enter linux coming from mac where there is only one strict chronological order of versions, and nothing can be altered.

Comment: BTW: If you have any suggestion for my other question about the shared clipboard, I would be very grateful.